# Grails: How to recreate a table without restart application (re-deploy)?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I've an application that should automatically drops a table if this table is old and recreate using new domain class.

I know that `Datasource.groovy` with `dbCreate=update` will do this for me. But I don't want to restart application.

I was expecting something like:

```
Customer.recreateDomainTable()
```

Note: to drop table I'm using:

```
Customer.withSession { session ->
session.createSQLQuery('drop table customer').executeUpdate() }
```

Comment: It sounds like a wish list request non existent methods will not work

Comment: I know that "recreateDomainTable" doesn't exists. I just added to be more clear which kind of feature I want to know if exists.